Past continuous and perfect with time expressions

I was sleeping for two hours when she came

I had been sleeping for two hours when she came


Only 2 is correct and 1 would be fine without time expression, right?
My thinking is that always when we display duration , how long something took before another event then we need perfect tenses just like my 2 example
Ps. You gave some examples where non perfect tenses were fine even though the duration was established. Can you make up some rule for me when it is fine to do so?

Not quite. There's nothing wrong with I was resting for a couple of minutes when she arrived. I'm not sure how to describe "rules" whereby my example is valid, but your first example isn't. It would also be okay to say I was away for few days when the hurricane hit our town, so it's not just a matter of how long you were doing something.

Your question is just "is this right?" which is off-topic for this site as it falls under proof-reading.

@FumbleFingers The example you have written is correct because you can plan to rest for a couple of minutes, so that's what you 'were' doing - having a couple of minutes rest, or taking forty winks. I don't think the OP's example is of someone planning to sleep for exactly 120 minutes.

@Astralbee: Yes, it's definitely something to do with that. Not necessarily planned activity, though, since I think you could reasonably say I was being kept on hold on the phone for several minutes when the doorbell rang. Something to do with referencing what you were doing as an action (that may take time to "complete") as opposed to as an activity (a "state of being", with no obvious "goal" or "completion" phase)?

Yet again, this is not a question of 'grammatical rules' but of whether anyone would be likely to say it. If you did routinely sleep for two hours every day, you would say something like I was having my two hours of sleep when she came. (1) just looks like a mistake for (2).

@Astralbee is right. Since I've seen most of your recent questions, I know "why" you're asking, but taking this question on its own, every question needs to say a bit more about why you think one way or the other might be right or wrong. Even with your background, this would be good because the reason you think so might need adjusting. Voting to close until edited.

This question is similar to: When is the past perfect exactly needed?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


My thinking is that always when we display duration , how long something took before another event then we need perfect tenses just like my 2 example

Well, the key here is the word "when." We can certainly express this situation in simple tenses if we use other connecting words:

I slept for two hours before she came.

Of course, this is ambiguous: the speaker may have woken up minutes before or hours before. We could add details to make it clearer:

I slept for two hours right before she came.

But we're still missing a sense that's present with "when": "When" is useful when we want to emphasize that the second part (a point in time) interrupts the first part (an ongoing action). This is where your statement that I quoted comes in. No, it doesn't generally work to say "I was sleeping for two hours when she came." But it's not really a language problem so much as a meaning problem. Consider these:

A. "What are you doing?" "I am cooking."
B. "What are you doing?" "I am cooking for two hours."
C. "Why do you seem tired?" "I have been cooking for two hours."

A is reasonable (I changed it to "cooking" because someone who is asleep can't talk about it): it says that an ongoing action is, well, ongoing, right now.
B is not reasonable. We're in the midst of that ongoing action; we don't know how long it will go on. (We're ignoring, for this conversation, the fact that you could use this present simple to state a plan—let's put that aside for now.)
C is reasonable. I could have used the same question in past tense, "What have you been doing," but I felt like changing it to be more realistic: For the answerer to mention the time duration, it would usually be for a reason: the point is not just the cooking but now long it was.
So "I was sleeping for two hours when she came" is a lot like example B above. It tries to interrupt an ongoing action with a single-point-in-time event, but it also tries to give a time duration. But since the action was interrupted, no one knows how long it would have been; if you had asked the sleeper during their sleep, "I am sleeping for two hours" wouldn't make sense (again, except as a plan, not talking about that usage here).

but we would not say for example "Before January we will be married for 25 years" we would say "Before January we will have been marries for 25 years". So, it isn't only about "when", is it?

@Gregor Well, it doesn't seem idiomatic to use "before" that way. You might say "In January we will have been married for etc." Or maybe the point is that in January it will become 26, and "up until" that time it's 25. It still doesn't work well with the "will have been," though, because in that case it's already 25 years right now.

@Gregor (Also, "Until January" is a sort of "when," since it could be reworded "when January happens.")

so then perfects are optional here because even with "when" it's grammatically correct and will be understood? What about examples like " I will be cooking for two hours before you come" or I will be doing it for 2 days by Monday". Are they fine to you without perfect?
